# Beautiful soup, get into app.start(text)

Tags: python

I have the gotten the following lxml code using beautifulSoup:

```
<script>
    app.start({
        el: $('body'),
        property: {
            p_A: 'A',
            p_B: 'B'
        });
</script>
```

from which I would like to get the list `{p_A : 'A', p_B : 'B'}`, but I do not know how to get into the `app.start`.

Comment: You can't parse it through Beautiful soup since that isn't HTML / XML.

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil
XML code, right sorry. I started using: 

r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

then I can navigate through soup but I got stuck at this point.

Comment: I don't know (but there might be tools/libraries) if this can be done without regex. You should try that.

Comment: you can try regex to extract property and then you can use json/yaml module to extract key,value pair

Comment: Okay, got it! I can indeed do it this way. Thank you

Comment: Starting with some specific URL i get to the point where I have:

`{'p_a' : 'a', 'p_b' : 'b', 'c', 'd'}`

But it doesn't want to convert this to a dictionary (using `st.literal_eval`), is there an easy way to make it ignore 'c' and 'd' or just add it as keys without values?